# Bash functions ignore set -e

Tags: linux, bash

How can I run a function as a "tested command" and perform action on failure, while still aborting the function as soon as an error occur?
Consider the following script

```
#!/bin/bash -e

function foo() {
   echo Entering foo
   false
   echo Should not reach this line
}

foo || echo I want to see this line on failure in foo
foo
```

The output I'm getting is

```
Entering foo
Should not reach this line
Entering foo
```

While I would like to get

```
Entering foo
I want to see this line on failure in foo
Entering foo
```

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to mark the function as untested command. According bash man page

```
 -e errexit
         Exit immediately if any untested command fails in non-interactive
         mode.  The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly
         tested if the command is part of the list used to control an if,
         elif, while, or until; if the command is the left hand operand of
         an “&&” or “||” operator; or if the command is a pipeline preceded
         by the ! operator.  If a shell function is executed and its exit
         status is explicitly tested, all commands of the function are con‐
         sidered to be tested as well.
```

**EDIT**
The expected output was wrong. edited it for clarity

Comment: See [BashFAQ/105 - Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping the code to do so in a utility function below.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# Runs given code aborting on first error and taking desired action on failure
# $1 code to invoke, can be expression or function name
# $2 error handling code, can be function name or expressions
function saferun {
  set +e
  (set -E ; trap 'exit 1' ERR ; eval $1) 
  [ $? -ne 0 ] && eval $2
  set -e
}

function foo() {
   echo Entering foo
   false
   echo Should not reach this line
}

saferun foo "echo I want to see this line on failure in foo"
foo
```

Let's break it down:

- `set +e` and `set -e` are used to suppress failure on error, as otherwise the script will just exit on first error
- `trap` is used to abort the execution on any error (instead of `set -e`) `()` is used to run the given code in subshell, so outer script will keep running after failure, and `set -E` is used to pass the trap into the subshell. so `(set -E ; trap 'exit 1' ERR ; eval $1)` run the given code / function aborting on first error while not exiting the whole script
- `$? -ne 0` check for failures and `eval $2` runs the error handling code

Answer (score 2):

`set -e` is disabled in the first call of `foo` since it's on the left hand side of `||`.

Also, you would never see the `I want to see this ...` string being outputted, unless the last `echo` in `foo` somehow failed (it's that last `echo` in `foo` that determines the exit status of the function).

```
foo() {
    echo Entering foo
    false && echo Should not reach this line
}

foo || echo I want to see this line on failure in foo
foo
```

The above outputs (with or without `set -x`)

```
Entering foo
I want to see this line on failure in foo
Entering foo
```

Now `false` is the last executed statement in `foo`.

Comment: How can have foo return when any command fails, on not just the last line? assuming I have some complex logic within foo

Comment: @Tzafrir Just don't use `foo` on the left hand side of `||`.