# bash `set -e` reset inside functions when run via `$(...)`?

Tags: bash, shell

It seems that the `set -e` option in Bash gets reset inside of functions, when those functions are invoked via a `$(...)` expansion.

This surprises me, and I'm not sure if it is a bug or not.
I have not been able to find a description of this behavior in the (usually quite thorough) Bash manpage.

Note: here are some other similar SO posts:

- [Bash functions ignore set -e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785352/bash-functions-ignore-set-e)
- [Using set -e / set +e in bash with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793264/using-set-e-set-e-in-bash-with-functions)

But neither of them deals with `$(...)`, which is not really discussed in the manpage either.

I also cannot find reference to this issue in the excellent [Bash FAQ 105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Here is a small program to demonstrate the issue:

```bash
echo "Initial:    $-"
set -eu
echo "After set:  $-"

function foo() {
    echo "Inside foo: $-"
}
foo

function bar() {
    false    # I'd expect this to immediately fail
    echo "Inside bar: $-"
}
# When a $(...) construct is involved, 'bar' runs to completion!
x=$(bar)
echo "We should never get here ... but we do."
echo "$x"
```

For me, on Bash version `5.0.11(0)-release`, I get the following output:

```
Initial:    hB
After set:  ehuB
Inside foo: ehuB
We should never get here ... but we do.
Inside bar: huB
```

So, as you can see, the `-u` option does get "passed through" to the function in all cases. And the `-e` option gets passed through when the function is called normally. But only in the special case of `$(bar)` does the `-e` option get reset.

Does anyone know if this is documented behavior, or otherwise explainable?

It makes no sense to me (:

Comment: The `$(…)` notation is [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and is described in the Bash manual.  It doesn't detail the interaction with `set -e`, though.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I don't understand what you mean; can you explain? There are no child processes involved here, just shell functions. Regardless, exporting that does not change the behavior in my sample program.

Comment: `just shell functions` - command substitution creates a child process. Och, there is `inherit_errexit` shopt

Comment: @KamilCuk: That is not true - you can verify by printing `$$` inside a shell function. It is the same number both inside and out.

Comment: Sure, now verify with `$BASHPID`. For `echo $BASHPID; $(echo $BASHPID >&2)` I see a different number. Still if you really want to, just read the [docs on command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) `executing command in a subshell environment`

Comment: @KamilCuk: ah, you're right. `$BASHPID` changes, as does `$BASH_SUBSHELL` (but not `$$`). So, it is not a new process in the OS, but a new subshell environment. Thanks for bearing with me (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of `set -e` in conjunction with [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) is documented in
[Command Execution Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment):

> Subshells spawned to execute command substitutions inherit the value of the `-e` option from the parent shell. When not in POSIX mode, Bash clears the `-e` option in such subshells.

That seems to say that the behaviour you see is expected — unless you're running in POSIX mode, the `-e` option is unset in command substitution subshells in Bash (even though the `-e` setting is initially inherited, it is changed soon after the subshell commences execution).  It's a funny way of writing it, though.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant `man` page quotes for you, first from the [Command Substiution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) section.

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:
>
> ```
>          $(command)
>    or
>          `command`
> ```
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing  newlines  deleted.

And from [Command Execution Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment):

> Subshells spawned to execute command substitutions inherit the value of the -e option from the parent shell.  When not in posix mode, bash clears the -e option in such subshells.

So `bar` get executed in a subshell, and since your are not in `posix` mode, the `-e` option gets cleared.

Add `set -o posix` to the start of you script and it will behave as expected, although expect other [differences](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/POSIX) when using this mode.